# AIR to ANDROID 2.1 - problem - what air/flex sdk?

Tags: android, apache-flex, sdk, air, flashdevelop

I am using flahsdevelop + android tools

I can create ANDROID 2.3 without any problems.

I have a problem compiling it to Android 2.1.

The AIR swf is compiled with flex 4.5 sdk + air 2.5 sdk.
Are these ok for android 2.1? 
If not, which versions of sdk I should be using?

Comment: I think the support for AIR has started as of Android 2.2. Could you try compiling it for 2.2?

Answer (score 3):

Adobe AIR for Android requires Android 2.2 or higher.  More info:

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/systemreqs/

You cannot developer Adobe AIR (or Flash Player web apps) targeting Android 2.1

Comment: Hi,

I am also using Flash Develop and have a similar problem. I tried to run install my apk on Android 2.2, but it says invalid apk file. But same file gets installed on Android 2.3 without any problem.

How can I specify which Android version my apk works?

Many thanks!